# String contains substring and substring not part of longer word (exact match)

Tags: string, vb.net, uipath

I have captured the full text of a PDF-file in a string called `pdfText`.

Next I am looping through an array containing substrings to be found/searched for in the `pdfText`-string.

One of the substrings is `Invoice`.

Both `pdfText` and the substrings I am searching for are converted to lower case.

If at least one of the substrings are found in the `pdfText`, a boolean is set to true.

Now, I have an example where the `pdtText` contains '...Net amount to be invoiced...'. This is the only variant of 'invoice' in the text.
This of course returns true if I use

`substring = "Invoice" ... pdfText.contains(substring.ToLower)`.

But in this case I need it to return false. I need to find only exact matches.

Another example, if the `pdfText` contains '...This is an invoice. Please pay....Net amount to be invoiced...' the boolean should be set to true because of the first invoice-match, but not the second invoiced-(non)match.

So what I am looking for is to find a substring `Invoice` in a string `pdfText` and make sure, that the substring is not part of a longer word `invoiced, invoice-process etc.`. Note, that `invoice.` should return `True`.

I believe this should be possible, but cannot wrap my head around it currently.
I might need to use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one uses the RegEx, with a slight change, proposed by @Mederic at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587916/2326360

Use the build in UiPath activity `Is Match`, found under `Programming->String`.

Use it inside your loop, with the current settings.

[image]

The RegEx is: `substring+"[^a-zA-Z]"`

I have declared the following variables:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RegEx would be a good approach.

I only started RegEx not long ago but I think this would work fine.

**RegEx:**

```
(invoice)[^a-zA-Z]
```

**Explanation:**

`()` Creates a Capture Group

`invoice` looks for the match for invoice

`[^a-zA-Z]` Checks there are no characters from a-z or A-Z after

**Example:**

---

Sample: This was invoiced

Result: No Result

---

Sample: This is an invoice.
Result: Match on `invoice.` Capture group 1 = `invoice`

---

**Implementation:**

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(pdfText.ToLower,"(invoice)[^a-zA-Z]")
' If successful, write the group.
If (m.Success) Then
    Dim key As String = m.Groups(1).Value
    Console.WriteLine(key)
End If
```

Comment: Instead of coding the RegEx matching, you should use the UiPath activities.

Comment: @NicolaiKrüger I'm not familiar at all with UiPath so i'll let you write up on that if you recommend it.